# Select rows from SQL where column doesn't match something in a string array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Let's say I have a table, `Product`, with a column called `ProductName`, with values like:

```
Lawnmower
Weedwacker
Backhoe
Gas Can
Batmobile
```

Now, I have a list, in Notepad, of products that should be excluded from the result set, i.e.:

```
Lawnmower
Weedwacker
Batmobile
```

In my real-life problem, there are tens of thousands of records, and thousands of exclusions. In SQL Studio Manager, how can I construct a query similar to the following pseudocode that will just return `Backhoe` and `Gas Can` as results?:

```
declare @excludedProductNames varchar(MAX) =
'Lawnmower
Weedwacker
Batmobile'

SELECT ProductName FROM Product
WHERE ProductName isn't in the list of @excludedProductNames
```

This is just a one-time report, so I don't care about performance at all.

Comment: `WHERE ProductName NOT IN ('Lawnmower', 'Batmobile', ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're best to use some text editor tricks to accomplish this. replace newlines with `', '` for example, and you can easily go for a `select * from product where ProductName not in ('...', '...')` query.

Answer (score 3):

First thing is getting those words into SSMS - you can construct a derived table using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 'Lawnmower' AS word
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Weedwacker'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Batmobile'
```

This will return a table with a single column, named "word":

```
word
--------
Lawnmower
Weedwacker
Batmobile
```

### Caveat

You'll need to escape any single quotes in your data.  IE: O'Brian needs to be changed to O''Brian--just double up the single quote to escape it.

Now, to the real query...

### Using NOT IN

Some databases limit the number of clauses in the IN, somewhere in the thousands IIRC so `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` might be better alternatives.

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE p.productname NOT IN (SELECT 'Lawnmower' AS word
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 'Weedwacker'
                             UNION ALL
                             SELECT 'Batmobile'
                             ...)
```

### Using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PRODUCT p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM (SELECT 'Lawnmower' AS word
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT 'Weedwacker'
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT 'Batmobile'
                           ...) x
                   WHERE x.word = p.productname)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL

```
   SELECT p.*
     FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'Lawnmower' AS word
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Weedwacker'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'Batmobile'
           ...) x ON x.word = p.productname
    WHERE x.word IS NULL
```

### Which is The Most Efficient/Fastest?

If the columns compared are not nullable, [NOT IN or NOT EXIST are the best choice](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).

Comment: Any way to get the data in there without having to edit thousands of lines adding SELECT '' to each line? (Can SQL parse it by Newline character?)

Comment: @routeNpingme: I use regex replace functionality in something like TextPad to insert characters for situations like that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table, load all your exclusions there and select all rows that do not exist in the temp table.

```
-- create temp table #exclusions
select ProductName into #exclusions
from Product
where 1 = 2

# run a bunch of inserts
insert into #exclusions (ProductName) values ('LawnMower')
-- as many as needed...

# run your select
select * from Product
where ProductName not in (select Product from #exclusions)

drop table #exclusions
```

As an alternative to running a ton of inserts, use [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to upload a csv file containing the ProductNames into a non temp table.